# Getting values from attribute table and inserting another table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have line feature class of a river network and “FromTo” table. Lines are dissolved so they are not segmented from junctions. I need to write a Python script in ArcGIS to do following:

1. Begin from the first row in Hydro feature class attribute table and get its ID
2. Insert this ID into “From” field in “FromTo” table
3. Get ID(s) of line(s) which intersect(s) first line (e.g. second line
   intersect first line)
4. Inset ID into “To” field in FromTo table

**For second loop**

5. Get ID of second row in Hydro feature class attribute table
6. Insert this ID into “From” field in “FromTo” table
7. Get IDs of lines which intersect second line (e.g. first and
   third lines intersect second line)
8. Inset IDs into “To” field in FromTo table
9. So on…

Perhaps, you show a different way in order to get the same result by Python

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do Strahler stream ordering with vector data? This describes the raster alternative http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z3000000

Comment: @PolyGeo: No, just trying to get connectivity of the network by creating this FromTo table.

Answer (score 5):

- See [arcpy.SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000) to iterate through a table or
  featureclass
- See [arcpy.InsertCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000038000000) to insert a value into a table or
  featureclass, and [arcpy.UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000) to edit an existing value
- See [Select By Location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000) to find features based on spatial relationships

Between those commands you can do most of what you're asking for.

**Update**: As per [Accessing data using cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) there is now *a new data access module (arcpy.da). The previously existing cursors are still functional and valid; however, the new arcpy.da cursors include significantly faster performance*

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be just wanting to know where your lines intersect, and which lines intersect at those locations, before going to Python, you may want to try:

1. [**Intersect**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) with just the one input feature class - works for all license levels
2. [**Tabulate Intersection**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000) if you have ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop Advanced