# Arcpy search cursor and update cursor to write values from table A to table B

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update, search

I'm a python beginner.

I`m working with ArcGIS 10.2.2 and IDLE Python 2.7.5

I have two tables, table A (top) and table B.

I need to read the attributes for the A-table fields for the selected record and write the fields and their attributes to all rows of the B table. I need the same attribute information for each row the fields.

[image]

I'm working with something like this

> ```
>    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, field3) as cursor:
>         for row in cursor:
>             row[0] = 'Q'
>             cursor.updateRow(row)
>     with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, field4) as ucursor:
>         with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, field5) as scursor:
>             for srow in scursor:
>                 sval = srow[0]
>                 urow = ucursor.next()
>                 urow[0] = "0" + sval.replace("-", "")
>                 ucursor.updateRow(urow)
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting values from attribute table and inserting another table using ArcPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/getting-values-from-attribute-table-and-inserting-another-table-using-arcpy)

Comment: Write values based on what? do you need to match values in table b or just create b as a copy of a?

Comment: I need an exact copy of A table (for the seleted record) for both of B's records. I've comptely read the cursor help docs and they don't have the syntax I need I'm working with something like this but it only works for two tables that have equal numbers of records and fields:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a function I call all the time for doing this, but first, you'll need a common field to join by.  From the screenshot, looks like you have a one to many relationship between the fields with several road names (`'{DEER HOLLOW WAY}{HUNTERS GLEN WAY}{HUNTERS GLEN WAY}'`) and those with single field names (`'DEER HOLLOW WAY'`). You'll want to make a field that you can use to match to the records in the second table. You may want to separate this out to a 1 to 1 relationship in a new table like this:

```
import os
import arcpy

def flattenTable(table, new_fc, read_field='STNAMES', new_field='JOIN_NAMES'):
    # make a copy of schema
    desc = arcpy.Describe(table)
    where = '{} < 0'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table, desc.OIDFieldName))

    path, name = os.path.split(new_fc)
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(table, path, name, where)

    # add new field
    fields = ['SHAPE@'] + [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table) if f.type not in ('OID','Geometry')]
    f_index = fields.index(read_field)
    arcpy.management.AddField(new_fc, new_field, 'TEXT', field_length=100)

    # search and insert cursors
    used = []
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(new_fc, fields + [new_field]) as irows:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as rows:
            for r in rows:
                st_names = set(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.strip('}'), r[f_index].split('{'))))
                # make overlapping features to flat 1M to 1 to 1 relationship
                for st in st_names:
                    if st not in used:
                        irows.insertRow(r + (st,))
                used += list(st_names)  # supress duplicates
    return new_fc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    table = r'C:\Path\to_your\create_position.shp'
    new_fc = r'C:\Path\to_your\create_position_1to1.shp'

    # change field variables if necessary

    # run it
    flattenTable(table, new_fc) #optional args for field names can be added
```

And finally, after you have added a common "join_field", you can call this function to add the fields.  Be sure to change the variables under the `__main__` block appropriately.

```
import arcpy
import os

FIELD_TYPES = {
    'Date':'DATE',
    'String':'TEXT',
    'Single':'FLOAT',
    'Double':'DOUBLE',
    'SmallInteger':'SHORT',
    'Integer':'LONG',
    'GUID':'GUID',
    'Raster':'RASTER'
    }

def CopyFields(source_table, in_field, join_table, join_key, join_values=[]):
    """
    Copies field(s) from one table to another

    Required:
        source_table -- table in which to add new fields
        in_field -- a field that has common values to a field in the join_table.
                    think of this as a "join_field"
        join_table -- table with fields to add to source_table
        join_key -- field to match values of the "in_field"
        join_values -- fields to add to source_table (list)
    """

    def Message(msg):
        print msg
        arcpy.AddMessage(msg)

    # Get Catalog path (for feature layers and table views)
    cat_path = arcpy.Describe(source_table).catalogPath

    # Find out if source table is NULLABLE
    if not os.path.splitext(cat_path)[1] in ['.dbf','.shp']:
        nullable = 'NULLABLE'
    else:
        nullable = 'NON_NULLABLE'

    # Add fields to be copied
    update_fields = []
    join_list = [f for f in arcpy.ListFields(join_table)
                 if f.type not in('OID', 'Geometry')]
    for field in join_list:
        ftype = field.type
        name = field.name
        length = field.length
        pres = field.precision
        scale = field.scale
        alias = field.aliasName
        domain = field.domain
        for fldb in join_values:
            if fldb == name:
                arcpy.AddField_management(source_table,name,FIELD_TYPES[ftype], pres, scale, length, alias, nullable, '', domain)
                Message("Added '%s' field to \"%s\"" %(name, os.path.basename(source_table)))
                update_fields.insert(join_values.index(fldb), name.encode('utf-8'))

    # update new fields
    #
    # Create Dictionary
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(join_table, [join_key] + join_values) as srows:
        path_dict = {r[0]: r[1:] for r in srows}

    # Update Cursor
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(source_table, [in_field] + update_fields) as urows:
        for row in urows:
            if row[0] in path_dict:
                try:
                    row[1:] = path_dict[row[0]]
                    urows.updateRow(row)
                except:
                    continue

    Message('Fields in "%s" updated successfully' %(os.path.basename(source_table)))
    return update_fields

if __name__ == '__main__':


    target_table = r'C:\Path\to_your\targetTable.shp'
    target_join_field = 'SOME_FIELD' # need to calculate this
    join_table = r'C:\Path\to_your\joinTable.shp'
    join_field = 'SOME_FIELD' # need to calculate this
    add_fields = ['QUADNAME', 'MAPNUM', 'EAM_STATUS', 'EAM_POSITION_ID'] #fields from join table to add

    # run it
    CopyFields(target_table, target_join_field, join_table, join_field, add_fields)
```